# can not install node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm trying to setup node-postgres for my project. However I keep getting these gyp errors when I try to install it. How can I get node-postgres to recognize that my pg_config is located in /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config. Because my favourite search engine results told me to do it like this:

```
➜  src git:(master) ✗ PG_CONFIG=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config
➜  src git:(master) ✗ export PG_CONFIG
➜  src git:(master) ✗ sudo npm install pg
Password:
npm WARN package.json test@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pg
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-writer/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pgpass/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pgpass/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-writer/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generic-pool/2.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/split
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/split
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/through
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through

> pg@2.11.1 install /Users/me/test/src/node_modules/pg
> node-gyp rebuild || (exit 0)

/bin/sh: pg_config: command not found
gyp: Call to 'pg_config --libdir' returned exit status 127.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/test/src/node_modules/pg
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
pg@2.11.1 node_modules/pg
├── nan@0.6.0
├── generic-pool@2.0.3
├── buffer-writer@1.0.0
└── pgpass@0.0.1 (split@0.2.10)
➜  src git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: I got this error in my dev environment in a workflow that "directly involve programming or programming tools", so not off-topic at all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the node build tool doesn't look at the `PG_CONFIG` env var:

> /bin/sh: pg_config: command not found

Add it to the `PATH` instead:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Awesome you! it looks like I have to dig into these export paths some more; I just don't get their purpose

Comment: @Egidius If a command is on the path, you can run it without specifying a full path. So `/bin/ls` can be run as simply `ls` because `/bin` is on the `PATH`. This is used by toolchains, compile/configure scripts, etc, to discover the location of things that could be installed anywhere on the system.